# How can I run a command after a cd ($pwd changes)?

Tags: powershell

I want to run a command that is going to look for a file `.mything-rc` in the current directory. I want to check if that file exist when I do a `cd`.

I mean, my command is not going to call `Set-Location`, I want something to execute automatically if the user call `Set-Location`... Something like what `nvm` does in bash, when you `cd` in a folder with `.nvmrc` it automatically runs a command `nvm use ...`

How can I detect that `$pwd` changed and run my command?

Comment: `$oldcwd = $pwd.Path; Set-Location ...; if ($oldcwd -ne $pwd.Path) { ... }`?

Comment: I mean, my command is not going to call `Set-Location`, I want something to execute automatically if the user call `Set-Location`... Something like what `nvm` does in bash, when you `cd` in a folder with `.nvmrc` it automatically runs a command `nvm use ...`

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a wrapper or proxy function for the `Set-Location` cmdlet. Have a look at [this Scripting Guy column](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/).

Comment: If you are after interactive users you could add your own prompt function to a profile detecting the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could append your custom `ScriptBlock` to the existing `prompt` function to check for a directory change and then do whatever you want:

```
$currentPrompt = (Get-Command prompt).ScriptBlock
$newLogic = { $global:old = $global:new; $global:new = Get-Location; if($null -ne $global:old -and $global:new.Path -ne $global:old.Path){ Write-Host "Location changed from '$global:old' to '$global:new'." } }
$newPrompt = [scriptblock]::Create("$currentPrompt; $newLogic")
function prompt { & $newPrompt }
```

Note that this relies on global variables so you should of course choose a better variable name than `old` and `new`.